# Win32 Error 8 during ccppc compile on Windows 7 x86

Tags: gcc, windows-7, makefile

I'm trying to compile a number of C source files with ccppc (version 3.3-e500). Most of the time, the compilations will fail, noting the following error

```
0 [main] cc1 {PID} sigproc_init: cannot create wait_sig thread, Win32 Error 8
```

I've looked up this Win32 error, and it corresponds to `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`. I'm quite certain that it's not an issue with physical memory, I have 4GB in this machine, with no more than 1.5GB in use at compile time. Unfortunately, I don't have local admin over my machine, and therefore cannot investigate issues with the pagefile.

After several failures, the source will eventually compile, and once all the source is compiled, there are no apparent issues with the outputted `.o`'s. However, this issue turns a 10-minute build into an hour+ build.

This issue is not present on XP x86 machines, I have not investigated x64 for either OS.

Has anyone run into an issue like this with ccppc or other gcc binaries on Windows 7? Any guidance in finding a solution would be awesome.

Comment: `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` doesn't refer to physical memory: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx. 32-bit processes on Windows only have 2GB of virtual address space, so if ccppc is using 1.5GB (I wasn't sure if that was usage just by that process or total system usage), it may be running out of contiguous virtual address space for memory allocation, causing the error. The solution might be to use a 64-bit compiler.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger To clarify, it was not `ccppc` that was using 1.5GB, that was the total usage at the time. You may be right regarding the 64-bit compiler, but unfortunately that's not an option :( There is legacy code in the codebase that's 16bit, and nearly a decade older than me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On moving from compiling under Windows XP 32-bit to Windows 7 64-bit, found that the cc1.exe program from gcc 2.96 for PowerPC was failing with the same error on some compiles. The investigation, using the Visual Studio Debugger to attach to cc1.exe and monitoring with Sysinternals tools, showed that:

1. When the cc1.exe program was successful it spawns 3 threads.
2. When the cc1.exe program failed, the 3rd CreateThread() call failed with `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`.
3. The image header of cc1.exe, as reported by running the Visual Studio `dumpbin /HEADERS` command, showed that the stack reserve size is 400000000 bytes. i.e. each thread created requires 400000000 bytes of contiguous virtual address space.
4. When the CreateThread call failed with `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY`, the Sysinternals VMMap tool showed that the maximum free virtual memory region was less than the requested stack reserve size of 400000000 bytes.
5. cc1.exe is a 32-bit process, which has 2Gbytes of virtual address space. Windows 7 has ASLR (Address space layout randomization), which causes the load address of DLLs to be randomized. I think that the ASLR is effectively fragmenting the virtual address spaces, such that on some invocations of the cc1.exe process the virtual addresses used by the loaded DLLs doesn't leave a large enough free region for the thread stacks. As well as the ASLR, in Windows 7 there was approx 4 times more DLLs loaded into the cc1.exe compared to under Windows XP which could be contributing to the problem.

Based upon the above investigation, the Visual Studio `editbin /STACK:67108864` program was used to reduce the stack reserve size for cc1.exe to 64Mbytes, where 64Mbytes was chosen as that was the stack reserve size for the cc1plus.exe program used for C++ code. With the reduction of the stack reserve size the `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` errors have not been seen again.

Comment: On a related note, compiling under Windows 7 the cc1.exe (for C) and cc1plus.exe (for C++) would fail with an internal error on some functions reporting that VirtualAlloc failed.

Setting `__COMPAT_LAYER=WinXP` in the environment appears to have prevented the VirtualAlloc failures. However, from searching I have been unable to find a description of what setting `__COMPAT_LAYER=WinXP` does under Windows 7, and why it stops the VirtualAlloc failures.

Comment: The best answer I ever faced.

Answer (score 0):

So, I never really found a solution, but I did manage to come up with a viable workaround.

Since the compile will eventually work after multiple re-`make`'s, you can wrap your `make` command in a do/while loop that checks the 'ERRORLEVEL' variable, and continues until it indicates success.

This obviously doesn't solve the "takes forever to compile" problem, but your compile will eventually succeed.

Comment: @ChesterGillon's answer provides a complete solution, but I'll leave this workaround up in case someone doesn't have access to Visual Studio for whatever reason.